Age is just a number!
If...

Colin is 14,
Caren is 33,
and
Anetta is 85 (and/or 86)

How old is Shamu?

Shamu is

 108.

Colin is

 is an anagram of silicon whose atomic number is 14.

Caren is

 is an anagram of arsenic, atomic number 33.

Anetta is

 is an anagram of astatine, atomic number 85.

But also,

 And or is an anagram of radon, atomic number 86.

So we see that Shamu is

 is an anagram of hassium, whose atomic number is 108!

I give my thanks to

 Lukas Rotter for the idea.


Exactly right, well deduced :) This was a fun short-and-sweet one to pull together when I spotted 'Colin is' while doing something else, and wondered if I could find others... 86 coming straight after 85 was the icing on the cake. Plus I enjoyed using the title, since here the age really just is a----- number!
